# Proper way to UPDATE nvidia driver

Tags: nvidia

I installed lower version accidentally and I want to upgrade to latest one? I couldn't find a solution online to do it all I see is to install it but I'm scared it would freeze my boot load again. Is there any proper way to update nvidia drivers. I'm using GTX 1050 ti currently installed 510 working smooth but I want the latest as much as possible. Currently the latest nvidia driver now for my graphic card is 515.

If I install new version, will it overwrites the old one and replace or install additional driver version?

**Update: It works by installing new version**

Comment: How did you downgrade the driver?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I purged the old one and install this 510

Comment: How did you install this driver? Can you not install the new driver in the same way?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi that's my last sort if so, but I'm looking if there's a better way to update without uninstalling the old version.

Comment: Between versions of the NVIDIA driver they have to be removed and the new one installed.  There is no way to go from `nvidia-driver-510` to `nvidia-driver-515` without removing 510 first.

Comment: The Software and Updates/Additonal Drivers tab offers the choice of available drivers.  I've only ever downgraded to the nouveau, but looks like any driver may be selected.